# On single server TFS systems should I set the SQL databases' recovery model to Simple or leave it on Full?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I recently had to go through every database on a SharePoint server and change the recovery model to simple because the logging was eating up disk space.

I don't have any apparent disk space problems on my TFS server, but wondered if there is a reason all the databases should be set to Full and not Simple.

Comment: Have you researched the differences between Full and Simple models and what the pros and cons are between the two?

Comment: Yes, I understand Full and Simple.  What I don't know and don't ever recall coming across is whether or not the TFS application requires Full mode for proper operation.  If not, then I could fall back to Simple mode to avoid potential disk growth issues, but I don't want to do that without knowing its impact on TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize the question had been addressed on ServerFault.  So I'm including a link to the answer here in case someone else searches for this on StackOverflow.

The answer is TFS requires Full recovery mode.

https://serverfault.com/questions/749510/tfs-db-and-recovery-model-is-simple-safe

Comment: @Alan, Since this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue here. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Got it.  Had to wait a certain # of days & forget to get back to it.  Thx!